# UI Autocomplete : Make multiple ajax requests or load all data at once for a list of locations in a city?

Tags: mysql, ajax, performance, autocomplete

I have a text box in my application which allows a user to select a location with the help of UI autocomplete. There are around **10,000** valid locations out of which the user **must** select one. There are two implementations for the autocomplete functionality:

1. Fetch the list of locations when the page loads for the first time and iterate over the array to find matching items on every keystroke in javascript
2. Make ajax requests on every keystroke as searching in MySQL(the db being used) is much faster?

Performance wise, which one is better?

An initial test shows that loading the data at once is the better approach from a performance point of view. However, this test was done on a MBP where JavaScipt processing is quite fast. I'm not sure whether this technique is the better one for machines with low processing power like lower end android phones, old systems etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question revolves around which is quicker, processing over 10,000 rows in the browser, or sending a request to a remote server to return the smaller result set. An interesting problem that depends on context and environment at runtime. Sending to the remote server incurs network delay mostly, with small amounts of server overhead.

So you have two variables in the performance equation, processing speed of the client and network latency. There is also a third variable, volume of data, but this is constant 10k in your question.

If both client browser and network are fast, use whatever you prefer.

If the network is faster, use the remote server approach, although be careful not to overload the server with thousands of little requests.

If the client is faster, probably use the local approach. (see below)

If both are slow, then you probably need to chose either, or spend lots of time and effort optimizing this.

Both clients slow can easily happen, my phone browser on 3G falls into this category, network latency for a random Ajax request is around 200mS, and it performs poorly for some JavaScript too.

As user perceieved performance is all that really matters, you could preload the first N values for each letter as variables in the initial page load, then use these for the first keystroke results, this buys you a few mS.

If you go with the server approach, you can always send requested result AND a few values for each of the next keystroke. This overlaps what users see and makes it appear snappier on slow networks. Eg

```
Client --> request 'ch'
Server responds with a few result for each potential next letter
    'cha' = ...
    'chb' = ...
    Etc
```

This of course requires some specialized javascript to alternate between Ajax requests and using cached results from previous requests to prefill the selection.

If you are going with the local client searching through all 10k records, then make sure the server returns the records in sorted order. If your autocomplete scanning is able to use 'starting with' selection rather than 'contains' (eg typing RO will match Rotorua but not Paeroa) then you can greatly reduce processing time by using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm techniques, and I'm sure there are lots of SO answers on this area.

Comment: I have edited the question with the details of an initial performance test. In your opinion, which approach is better for machines with low processing power?

Comment: Opinion? Go with JavaScript doing all since there is only 10k records. However if most users are low end and this field is used lots, test it, otherwise you might annoy your users. Updated text slightly.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no advantage for querying the backend every time, don't do it.

What could be an advantage of querying the backend all the time? If the amount of returned data for the initial call is to heavy (bandwidth, javascript processing time to prepare it, time at all), the partial request every time could be the smarter option.